# How can I disable use of default 'LaunchScreen.storyboard' (Qt 5.15 for iOS)?

Tags: iphone, qt, qmake

I use my custom launch screen (storyboard-file) and need to disable default one, generated by qmake, to be bundled either. How can I do that?

Looking under the hood there is a code in 'mkspecs/features/uikit/default_post.prf' that does the job. How to inactivate that code (without changing the Qt's sources)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your own Launch.storyboard file you have to add something like this in your .pro file:

```
ios {
    QMAKE_INFO_PLIST = ios/Info.plist
    ios_icon.files = $$files($$PWD/ios/*.png)
    QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA *= ios_icon

    app_launch_images.files = $$files($$PWD/ios/splash_image.png)
    QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA *= app_launch_images
    app_launch_screen.files = $$files($$PWD/ios/Launch.storyboard)
    QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA *= app_launch_screen
 }
```

With that options Qt should use your custom file instead of the default one.

Comment: My custom launch screen (storyboard-file) is invoked, no problems. A little bit problem is that the default one is also compiled and bundled (qmake generates such code). I want to remove that unused stuff from the app's bundle and reduce compilation time as well. The solution you provided, I think, acts the same. You need see no "CompileStoryboard congregation.xcodeproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard" in the build output.